# Pass a value from the javascript in a user control to a webform

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

Right now, I have a user control that raises an event which the webform handles with a handler.  It is a typical set up with a delegate, an event, and a handler working together.

But I am trying to do the same but all with javascript.  The user control calls a webservice to process a task, and gets a value.

```
function performsomething(){

  //calls webservice
  WS.CallWebService(valPassed, onSuccess, onfail);

}


function onSuccess(result){
  //result is for Webform to handle in its script.  How can I pass it to the webform?
}

function onfail(){
    alert('something bad happened');
}
```

So once "result" comes back from the webservice, I want the webform's javacript to take it from there and do whatever it needs to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To call a javascript function from code behind you should

**JavaScript:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(result) {
        alert('this is my result:' + result);
    }
  </script>
```

**C#:**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","myFunction(result)",true);
```